# Loss Function for Minimizing Space Between Output Values

Tags: functions, partial-derivative, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I have a constant input vector $I$ and a variable matrix $N$. (I know that matrixes aren’t usually $N$, but in this case, it stands for *Neural Network*)

I’m building a program that uses the gradient of some error function $E$ to change the values inside the matrix $N$, so that $E(NI)$ approaches a local (and hopefully global) minimum as the program continues.

However, the error function $E$ that I want is kinda weird. Given a vector $V$, $E(V)$ should compute the greatest difference between two numerically sequential values in the vector.

That is, if $V=(1,3,7)$, E(V)=4 because 7-3=4 and 3-1=2, and 4>2, and therefore 4 is the answer.

Now, if the formula were just

$$E(V) = \max_{x} V_{x+1} - V_{x}$$

where $V_x$ is the $x$th entry in the vector $V$, that might make this question easier. However, it is not, because V is not always numerically ordered.

That is, if $V=(3,1,7)$ or $V=(7,3,1)$, $E(V)$ should still be 4. As another example, $E((1,3,2,7))=4$ as well.

So, I have two questions that build on each other.

1. **What is a formula for $E$?** (Or show that there cannot be such a formula using math notation)
2. **Is there a formula for $E(NI)$ which is differentiable** with respect to entries in $N$, as a function of $N$ and $I$? (If not, why not? If so, what is it?)

(Note that since I’ve only defined $E(V)$ for a vector $V$, we can assume that $N$ has dimensions such that $NI$ results in a *vector* (that is, a two-dimensional matrix with one dimension being 1))

Comment: This question is a stepping stone for me - I’m actually looking for something that will convert the output of a network into a cumulative distribution along each axis in a differentiable way, but I felt like answers to this question might lead me to that answer. (And I’m not exactly sure how to phrase my real question clearly yet, as you may be able to tell.)